# Eclipse RCP Data Binding with WritableValue - Int vs. Integer

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-rcp

I'm using Eclipse RCP 4 and I've little problem with my `WritableValue`:

I use the `WritableValue` in a data binding (see below) and whenever I set the value of my `WritableValue` with an object that contains an int attribute (part of the binding), then I receive a `ClassCastException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int
 at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.beans.PojoValueProperty.doGetValue(PojoValueProperty.java:62)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.property.value.ValueProperty.getValue(ValueProperty.java:60)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue.notifyIfChanged(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.property.value.SimplePropertyObservableValue.doGetValue(SimplePropertyObservableValue.java:101)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.getValue(AbstractObservableValue.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.observable.masterdetail.DetailObservableValue.doGetValue(DetailObservableValue.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.observable.masterdetail.DetailObservableValue$2.handleValueChange(DetailObservableValue.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:71)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.ChangeManager.fireEvent(ChangeManager.java:127)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.fireValueChange(AbstractObservableValue.java:76)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.WritableValue.doSetValue(WritableValue.java:94)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.AbstractObservableValue.setValue(AbstractObservableValue.java:60)
```

This is my binding:

```
IObservableValue<?> model2 = PojoProperties.value(PlantBE.class,
            "maxAge").observeDetail(getModel().getWritableValue());
ISWTObservableValue<String> view2 = WidgetProperties.textText(SWT.Modify)
            .observe(getDialogView().getTxtMaxAge().getText());
this.getDataBindingContext().bindValue(model2, view2);
```

The Entity (PlantBE) looks like that:

```
public class PlantBE implements Serializable {
private int maxAge;

public int getMaxAge() {
    return maxAge;
}

public void setMaxAge(int maxAge) {
    this.maxAge = maxAge;
}
}
```

It would be great to get some help on that. Maybe you've an idea what the issue could be.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

What does the `getModel().getWritableValue()` return? Why wouldn't you do it like this:

```
IObservableValue model= BeanProperties.value(PlantBE.class,"maxAge").observe(model);
IObservableValue view = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify).observe(getDialogView().getTxtMaxAge());
this.getDataBindingContext().bindValue(model, view);
```

ALso, take a look at [this holy Eclipse RCP grail, aka Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html), it should help you a lot understanding this whole data binding mess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though this is not my problem. I try to give you some more detail: The getModel()getWritableValue() returns a WritableValue<PlantBE>, the attribute "maxAge" within the PlantBE should be bound (compare code above). I cannot use BeanProperties because PlantBE is no bean. Though I've tried BeanProperties as well and it was working but obsiviously I get some exceptions that some methods are missing. Thanks for the link, but I've studied that more than once ;) and WritableValues is a minor topic.

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by "PlantBE is not a bean", because it is enough for class to be a pojo. Also, you could check which methods does it complaining about. As per your implementation, then another obvious solution would be to change the type of the maxAge from int to an Integer.

Comment: This is a bean: A Java Bean is a Java object which follow the Java Bean specification. This specification requires that the class implements getter and setter methods for all its attributes. It must also implement property change support via the PropertyChangeSupport class and propagate changes to registered listeners. (Vogella) Sadly maxAge cannot be changed to Integer.